# Globbing not working as expected

Tags: zsh, glob

I would like to list all plain files that are not python scripts in `zsh`.
Why does the following "code" not work and what is the proper solution?

```
ls -l *(.)~*.py
```

UPDATE:

I have `setopt extended_glob` in my `.zshrc`.
And

```
ls -ld *~*.py``
```

works as expected. 
(I added the `-d` in the command to prevent directories from getting expanded).

Comment: Do you have the `EXTENDED_GLOB` option set, which is required for `~`?

Comment: Thanks for asking. Question is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `~` is a glob *operator* (that also requires `EXTENDED_GLOB` be set), while `(.)` is a glob *qualifier*, which means it must be added to the end of the entire pattern, not used in the middle. Use

```
ls *~*.py(.)
```

instead. That is, `*~*.py` is your pattern (all files not ending in `.py`), and `(.)` is applied to the results. (Perhaps yet another way to put it is to say that glob operators can only work on *unqualified* patterns.)

Comment: Also note that you shorten this pattern to `^*.py(.)`